# Aggregate dataframe indices in python

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to aggregate indices of a dataframe with groupby function.

```
     word  count
0    a     3
1    the   5
2    a     3
3    an    2
4    the   1
```

What I want is a pd.Series which consists of list(descending order) of indices,

```
word
a       [2, 0]
an         [3]
the     [4, 1]
```

I've tried some built-in functions with groupby, however, I couldn't find a way to aggregate indices. Would you like to provide any hint or solution for this problem?

Comment: So you drop the `tag` and `count` columns?

Comment: @IanS Well yes. For this question, those columns are useless. I just put it to emphasize the data is a dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can first change order of `index` by `[::-1]`, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `apply` `index` to `list`. Last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
print (df[::-1].groupby('word', sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()).sort_index())
word
a      [2, 0]
an        [3]
the    [4, 1]
dtype: object
```

Another similar solution:

```
print (df.sort_index(ascending=False)
         .groupby('word', sort=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())
         .sort_index())
word
a      [2, 0]
an        [3]
the    [4, 1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to get used to lambda function!

Comment: Glad can help you!